# LangChain WebResearchRetriever excedding context length

Tags: openai-api, agent, langchain, large-language-model

I am currently developing an agent chatbot using LangChain's [`WebResearchRetriever`](https://python.langchain.com/docs/modules/data_connection/retrievers/web_research) class. However, the context returned by the `WebResearchRetriever` always exceeds the maximum token length allowed by the OpenAI's `gpt-3.5-turbo` model, which is 4097 tokens. Are there any ways to stop this agen from using a context length greater than the model's context length? Below is my code for the agent:

```
# Initialize properties
vectorstore = Chroma(embedding_function=OpenAIEmbeddings(), persist_directory="./chroma_db_oai")
llm = ChatOpenAI(model_name="gpt-3.5-turbo", temperature=0.3)
memory = AgentTokenBufferMemory(memory_key="chat_history", llm=llm, return_messages=True, max_token_limit=2048)
llm.max_tokens = 2048

# Initialize Google Search Retriever
search = GoogleSearchAPIWrapper()

web_research_retriever = WebResearchRetriever.from_llm(
    vectorstore=vectorstore,
    llm=llm, 
    search=search, 
    num_search_results=1,
    text_splitter=RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter.from_tiktoken_encoder(chunk_size=512, chunk_overlap=0, model_name="gpt-3.5-turbo"),
    url_database=["a-hospital.com", "120ask.com", "dxy.cn", "zhihu.com", "baidu.com", "ewsos.com", "wikipedia.org"]
)

# Initialize the agent tools
tool = create_retriever_tool(
    web_research_retriever, 
    "medical_web_retriever",
    "Researches and returns information in the internet about any medical-related topics."
)
tools = [tool]

# Initialize the agent
# TODO: prompt engineer the system message so that it selects the context when it needs; it now does not select any concept
system_message = SystemMessage(
        content=(
            "Do your best to answer the questions. "
            "Feel free to use any tools available to look up for professional medical information."
            "If you encounter a new medical concept that has not appeared in the conversation before, e.g., a medicine or a symptom, you should carry out a web research of it."
            "If a medical concept has been asked before, you should check the pre-researched information before deciding to research about any aspects of the concept even more."
        )
)
prompt = OpenAIFunctionsAgent.create_prompt(
        system_message=system_message,
        extra_prompt_messages=[MessagesPlaceholder(variable_name="chat_history")]
    )
agent = OpenAIFunctionsAgent(llm=llm, tools=tools, prompt=prompt)

agent_executor = AgentExecutor(agent=agent, tools=tools, memory=memory, verbose=True, return_intermediate_steps=True)
result = agent_executor({"input": "什么是连花清瘟胶囊？"})
print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Two important things that will help you control the context length.

1. Make sure your prompt is very well defined, to your SystemMessage you can add one more point which says "Your response should be concise and should not exceed two to three sentences."
2. Define tool description as

   ```
   description="useful for when you need to research short answers for any medical-related topics"
   ```